# Qt creator + CMake. Как заставить проект собираться в многопоточном режиме?

Tags: c++, qtcreator, cmake, сборка

Пишу проект на с++, который уже разросся, и время компиляции давно перевалило за 3 минуты. Сегодня заметил, что сборка проекта происходит в однопоточном режиме, хотя в настройках среды стоит флаг -j4.

[image: Экранный снимок диспетчера задач Ubuntu]

[image: Qt Creator, параметры, передаваемые CMake]

Как мне заставить CMake собирать проект на нескольких ядрах или заставить Qt Creator запускать CMake в таком режиме?

Comment: Генерируйте Makefile: `cmake –G”Unix Makefiles”`. А дальше запускаете `make --jobs 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым. Надо было добавить флаг -j4 в Build Steps -> Build.

[image: Qt Creator, параметры, передаваемые CMake]

Сборка ускорилась примерно в 2.5 раза.